# Error "decoding str is not supported" Custom str Class Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation, typeerror, unpack

I was building a class that would work like a switch;

such custom class would have been a string, with an inner list, whereas the string identifies the current position of the switch ("on") and the list covers all the possible positions (["on","off","halfway on", "kinda dead but still on", ...];

While initializing an instance of this class, I would accept an indefinite number of possible positions;

Hence the code

```
class switch(str):
    pos=[]
    def __init__(self,*positions):
        self.pos=[str(el) for el in positions]
        self=self.pos[0]
    def swap(self):
        try:
            self=self.pos[self.pos.index(self)+1]
        except IndexError:
            self=self.pos[0]
```

and the call

`mood=switch("upbeat","depressed","horny")`

That quite doesn't work. The error goes like this:

`TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Of course there are better ways to make this Switch class (this was just a draft of a quick insertion) and eventually, I already did; still I didn't understand the origins of that error - whose search through Google wasn't useful - and angered enough about it that I finally decided to sign up here on Stack and post about it.
What do you guys think about it?

Googling it up, it seems like the error would turn off when trying to concatenate strings like `"str1","str2"` and not like `"str1"+"str2"`; then I think it's safe to keep suspicions around the `*positions` thing, with it not unpacking the strings as separate variables, but trying to guess I wanted them to be joined as one but failed at it as I wasn't using the + concatenator.

That's what came to my mind.

Otherwise, if I'm wrong, I've seen the error pop up only while playing with formats and stuff. Which is pretty way off in this case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough. We need to see enough code that we can copy and paste it and see the problem for ourselves; and we need to see a complete exception traceback (copied and pasted, starting from the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line, and formatted like code).

Comment: As an aside, `pos=[]` in your class does **not** "declare" a `pos` attribute for instances; it creates a *separate* attribute that belongs *to the class itself*, and which is hidden by the instances' attribute. There is no need to declare anything and no purpose for this line.

Comment: That said: inheriting from built-in types is not going to work the way you seem to expect, and assigning to `self` doesn't modify the object (for the same reason that `b = [1]; a = b; a = [2]` doesn't cause `b` to become `[2]`).

Comment: You don't want to make a class that's a kind of string, because *you can't meaningfully do all the things with your class that a string can do*. You want to make a class that *encapsulates* a string value, with an interface to get that value. One possibility, especially suited for "one of multiple constant possibilities", is an `Enum` type.

Comment: Thanks! Couple of things weren't clear to me. At the end, the closest solution I figured out based on these suggestions and Mark's answer was a class that doesn't inherit str, has a string as inner value and custom __repr__ and __eq__ functions, so that it works exactly as it meant to be as a string subclass. Didn't quite understand the reason of what you wrote in the third comment, tho

Answer (score 3):

You *can* subclass `str`. But if you are passing more than a single argument, you need to intercept that at `__new__()` so python doesn't try to interpret the other arguments when creating the object.

*Note this is just to demonstrate —* **it won't work for your problem**

```
class switch(str):
    def __new__(cls, *content):
        return str.__new__(cls, content[0])

    def __init__(self, *positions):
        self.pos = [str(el) for el in positions]
    
mood=switch("upbeat", "depressed", "horny")

# prints as expected and has string methods
print(mood, mood.upper())
# upbeat UPBEAT

# has your instance attribute
print(mood.pos)
['upbeat', 'depressed', 'horny']
```

The problem is that strings are not mutable. So this is doomed from the beginning if the idea is to change the value of the string in-place. You *can* instead use [`collections.UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) for this. This acts like a string but gives you a `data` property to store the actual value. With this, your idea might work:

```
from collections import UserString

class Switch(UserString):
    def __init__(self, *positions):
        self.pos = [str(el) for el in positions]
        # store the actual string in .data
        self.data = self.pos[0]
        
    def swap(self):
        try:
            self.data = self.pos[self.pos.index(self)+1]
        except IndexError:
            self.data = self.pos[0]

    
mood=Switch("upbeat", "depressed", "horny")

# still acts like a string
print(mood, mood.upper())
# upbeat UPBEAT

# but now you can swap 
mood.swap()
print(mood, mood.upper())
# depressed DEPRESSED
```

Comment: Thanks! Got the problem. At the end, I kept it simple by using a class that doesn't inherit Str nor UserString, has an inner variable like that `data`, and to make it work as a string (both for printing and comparing, `print(mood)` and `mood=="happy"`) I just modified its __eq__ and __repr__ functions. Works just as it was meant to be as a str subclass!

Comment: Huh, I had forgotten `UserString` (and `UserList` and `UserDict`) still existed. Weren't they originally workarounds from when it wasn't possible to inherit from the builtins?

Comment: Yes @KarlKnechtel, they are mostly depreciated (the docs say "partially supplanted by") since you can directly subclass these types. However, they can still be useful when you want a wrapper in special cases like the above, which (I don't *think*) can be solved with a direct subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think Python thinks you're using the second constructor of `str()`  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

e.g. `switch(b"upbeat", "utf-8")` would work.

Comment: But the OP wants to pass in three arguments: `switch("upbeat","depressed","horny")`. How would this work in your solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).